Azure webapp deployment with replacable token in configuration
I have run into some difficulties with a deployed azure web api. I have the deployment pipeline set up in 5 stages: ci, dev, test, acc, prod. I then have the infrastructure deploy job AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment (in the dev/test/acc/prod stage) output a storage uri. Then use DownloadPipelineArtifact, replacetokens and AzureWebApp tasks to deploy.
The configuration is added to the application like so:
private static void AddConfig(this WebApplicationBuilder builder, string fileName)
    => builder.Configuration
           .AddJsonFile($"{configDir}/{fileName}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
           .AddJsonFile($"{configDir}/{fileName}.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

I have verified in the deployed files that the token is correctly replaced in the json file, yet when I send a request to a debugging endpoint I made (just to return the configured uri) it presents me with #{StorageUri}#.
Debug controller for reference:
public class DebugController(IOptions<StorageSettings> settings) : BaseController
{
    private readonly IOptions<StorageSettings> _settings = settings;

    [HttpGet("Get")]
    public async Task<string> Get()
    {
        return _settings.Value.StorageUri;
    }
}

My best guess is that the configuration jsons are no longer used after compiling, and the dll will have the value from the file already. I do not wish to build the application for every environment individually, but rather download the artifact for each stage and replace the tokens before deploying. Is there any way to achieve it in this fashion? I have also tried using IConfigurationRoot.Reload() but to no avail.
EDIT:
The executed pipeline yml is as follows:
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - ${appname}$/src/**
    exclude:
    - ${appname}$/tests/**
pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
stages:
- stage: CI
  displayName: "Integration"
  jobs:
  - job: BuildTestPublish
    displayName: "Build and test the application, then publish the artifact."
    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: "NuGet Restore"
      inputs:
        command: "restore"
        projects: |
          ${appname}$/*.sln
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: "Build and publish the Artifact"
      inputs:
        command: "publish"
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: |
          ${appname}$/*.sln
        arguments: "-o $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Output -c Release"
        zipAfterPublish: false
    - task: VSTest@2
      displayName: "Run Automated Tests"
      inputs:
        testAssemblyVer2: |
          **\*.UnitTests.dll
          **\*.IntegrationTests.dll
        platform: "$(buildPlatform)"
        configuration: "$(buildConfiguration)"
        searchFolder: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Output"
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: "Publish the build artifacts"
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Output"
        ArtifactName: "${appname}$"
- stage: cdDev
  displayName: Deploy to Development
  variables:
  - name: envName
    value: dev
  - name: serviceConnectionName
    value: ${service_connection}$
  - name: resourceGroupName
    value: ${resource_group}$
  dependsOn:
  - CI
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - job: infraDeploy
    displayName: "Deploy Infrastructure"
    steps:
    - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
      inputs:
        connectedServiceName: ${service_connection}$
        deploymentName: $(Build.Buildnumber)
        location: ${location}
        resourceGroupName: $(resourceGroupName)
        csmFile: infrastructure/main.bicep
        csmParametersFile: infrastructure/main.bicepparam
        overrideParameters: |
          -environmentSuffix $(envName)
        deploymentOutputs: deploymentOutputs
    - task: PowerShell@2
      name: "outputVariables"
      displayName: "Set Deployment Output Variables"
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          $armOutputObj = '$(deploymentOutputs)' | ConvertFrom-Json
          $armOutputObj.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
            $keyname = $_.Name
            $value = $_.Value.value

            Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$keyName;issecret=false;isOutput=true]$value"

            Write-Output "Output variable: $keyName"
            Write-Output "Output value: $value"
          }
        pwsh: true
  - job: softwareDeploy
    displayName: "Deploy Software"
    dependsOn:
    - infraDeploy
    variables:
    - name: storageUri
      value: $[ dependencies.infraDeploy.outputs['outputVariables.storageUri'] ]
    steps:
    - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
      inputs:
        artifactName: "${appname}$"
        path: "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${artifactname}$"
    - task: replacetokens@6
      displayName: "Replace Tokens"
      inputs:
        sources: |
          $(Pipeline.Workspace)/${artifact_name}$/appsettings*.json
          $(Pipeline.Workspace)/${artifact_name}$/Configurations/*.json
        tokenPattern: "custom"
        tokenPrefix: "#{"
        tokenSuffix: "}#"
        addBOM: true
        missingVarAction: "keep"
        missingVarLog: "error"
        ifNoFilesFound: "error"
    - task: AzureWebApp@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: ${service_connection}$
        appName: ${appname}$-app-$(envName)
        package: "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${artifact_name}$"

Cut the test, acc, and prod stage as they are repeats of dev with different values, and replaced some info with ${value}$ tokens.

Hi, can you please share the full yaml file you are using? I noticed that you said I have verified in the deployed files that the token is correctly replaced in the json file. How did you verify this? From this #{StorageUri}#, it looks like the token was not replaced successfully.  In addition, you can also try to deploy an artifact with a hard code StorageUri and see if the correct StorageUri will appear during debugging.

I have split the stages, jobs, and steps into separate yml files to use as templates but I can piece it together if you'd like. Regarding the deployed file, I used the App service editor to browse the deployed files. In there the json file contains the correct storage uri. This leads me to believe the configuration files are used at compile-time instead of runtime.

Hi, you don't need to piece it together. You can edit the pipeline and choose Download Full YAML, this will download the YAML that actual run in the pipeline. You can remove some private information before sharing the downloaded YAML. Can you please deploy an artifact with a hard code StorageUri and see if it works? This way we can narrow down the issue that if it is with the replace task or the artifact itself.

I have added the pipeline yml to the post, and also done a run with the uri hardcoded. Strangely enough it still returns #{storageUri}# instead of the connection uri. So the fault probably lies within C# rather than the token replacement.

After some more investigating it turned out that my definition for the class the settings were bound to was incorrect. I had the property set as public string storageUri = "#{storageUri}#";, which works during program startup. But when later injected using IOptions<StorageSettings> it contained the token value again. By changing this to public string storageUri { get; set; } = default!; it correctly replaces it every time. Thanks a bunch for pushing me in the right direction!

Hi, thanks for your update. It looks like the problem occurs in your code. I suggest that you can double-check how the configuration values ​​are being accessed in your C# code. You can add additional logging to your application to verify that the configuration values ​​are being read correctly. In addition, you can try searching for #{storageUri}# throughout the entire codebase. This will help you find any instances where the placeholder might be used or incorrectly referenced and can help identify where the issue might be occurring.

Solved: the issue was not with the token replacement or config reading, but rather with the class the json was bound to.
public string storageUri = "#{storageUri}#"; is correctly replaced during startup, but not after injection.
public string storageUri { get; set; } = "#{storageUri}#" is correctly replaced every time. Thanks to Miao Tian-MFST for helping me find this.
